# Why are my PNG bytes different?

Tags: android, png

I am trying to read the bytes of Android's `192x192` **ic_launcher.png** (the `mipmap-xxxhdpi` version).

Here is what I'm doing:

```
Drawable drawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawableForDensity
            (getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher, 640, getTheme());

Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();

ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);

byte[] pngBytes = stream.toByteArray();

Log.d("TEST", "" + pngBytes[37]);
```

I am comparing the results using a Hex-Editor on the file `app\src\main\res\mipmap-xxxhdpi\ic_launcher.png`.

For some reason, the byte at `pngBytes[37]` is **different** than the actual byte. The bytes before are identical.

What may cause such a thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For some reason, the byte at pngBytes[37] is different than the actual byte.

Well, sure. Most likely, there will be quite a few differences. There is no requirement for `compress()` to give you an identical PNG file than what you started with, as there can be:

- different compression levels
- different color palette (e.g., build process might apply `pngquant`-style techniques to your resource)
- different pixel formats (indexed vs. simple ARGB)
- and so on

Comment: Thanks. How can I get the actual bytes?

Comment: @UFCInsider: Move the PNG into `res/raw/`, then use `openRawResource()` on a `Resources` object. Or, move the PNG into `assets/`, then use `open()` on an `AssetManager`. Either of those will give you an `InputStream` on the raw resource or asset, and those files should not be modified as part of the build process.

Comment: Is there a way to get the actual bytes programmatically? I don't want to move the PNG

Comment: @UFCInsider: Then you are not necessarily going to get "the actual bytes" from the original resource file, as the build process may modify PNG files to reduce the size of your APK. I have heard rumors that `openRawResource()` actually works with all resource types, but I have not tried this and do not know if that behavior will be reliable. So, if you want to read in the bytes of the possibly-modified PNG file, you're welcome to try that.

Comment: Say I have moved all the `ic_launcher` files to `raw`. How can I get the `inputstream` for the `192x192` one (without giving it a unique name)?

Comment: @UFCInsider: By definition, if they are all in `res/raw/`, they must have unique names, as a single directory cannot have N files with the same name. If you use `res/raw-.../` (e.g., `res/raw-xxxhdpi/`), I am not aware of a way of getting at that specific density's raw resource.